# Android Navigation Instrument Test Exception

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-testing, android-architecture-navigation

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread.**

@Test
fun verifyAllRequiredViewsAreDisplayed() {

```
val navController = TestNavHostController(
    ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
)

navController.setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_onboarding)

// Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
val userEmailScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<EmailFragment>()

// Set the NavController property on the fragment
userEmailScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
    Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
}

assertThat(navController.currentDestination?.id).isEqualTo(R.id.emailFragment)
```

}

Comment: Any solution, I have the same problem?

Comment: Can this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686001/android-navigation-instrumentation-test-throws-method-addobserver-must-be-called The `LifecycleRegistry` verify the method on main thread since 2.3.0 https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.3.0