# How can I launch a fragment with safe args in an instrumentation test?

Tags: android-fragments, androidx, android-navigation, android-safe-args

Below I have a test class designed to launch a fragment in isolation and test the navController's ability to navigate.

The first test, `landingToGameFragmentTest()` works perfectly!

The second test launches a fragment that depends on safe args to be passed to it. Aside from that, there is no difference I can perceive in how they are executed.

```
// Declare navController at top level so it can be accessed from any test in the class
private lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

// Use Generic type with fragment as upper bound to pass any type of FragmentScenario
private fun <T : Fragment> init(scenario: FragmentScenario<T>) {

    // Create a test navController
    navController = TestNavHostController(
        ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    )

    scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        // Link navController to its graph
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
        // Link fragment to its navController
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    }
}

@Test
fun landingToGameFragmentTest() {

    init(launchFragmentInContainer<LandingFragment>(themeResId = THEME))

    // Click button to navigate to GameFragment
    onView(withId(R.id.button_start_game))
        .perform(click())

    assertEquals("Navigation to GameFragment failed",
        R.id.gameFragment,
        navController.currentDestination?.id)
}

@Test
fun gameToLandingFragmentTest() {

    init(launchFragmentInContainer<GameFragment>(themeResId = THEME, fragmentArgs = Bundle()))

    onView(withId(R.id.button_end_game))
        .perform(click())

    assertEquals("Navigation to LandingFragment failed",
        R.id.landingFragment,
        navController.currentDestination?.id)
}
```

I set a default value for its arguments, but I still got a null arguments exception until I passed it an empty bundle. Now the fragment will launch but it appears not to be able to navigate to any other fragment!

I could find no similar questions on SO, and the stack output is beyond me.

After the `init(launchFragmentInContainer())` line I stepped through the code and found this throwing an `illegalArgumentException`:

```
public static int parseInt(@RecentlyNonNull String s, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Which then leads to `getNavigator()`, which passes the name "fragment".
However the only navigators are "navigation" and "test", of which I believe it should be test.
The `illegalStateException` is then thrown:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a registered [Navigator] by name.
 *
 * @param name name of the navigator to return
 * @return the registered navigator with the given name
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the Navigator has not been added
 *
 * @see NavigatorProvider.addNavigator
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@CallSuper
public open fun <T : Navigator<*>> getNavigator(name: String): T {
    require(validateName(name)) { "navigator name cannot be an empty string" }
    val navigator = _navigators[name]
        ?: throw IllegalStateException(
            "Could not find Navigator with name \"$name\". You must call " +
                "NavController.addNavigator() for each navigation type."
        )
    return navigator as T
}
```

Finally `navigate()` is called on `onView(withId(R.id.button_end_game))` generating:

[image: illegalArgumentException on navigate()]

I likely don't have to keep this test in this specific instance. However, I certainly will need to know how to launch a Fragment in isolation (that depends on safe args) in the future.

Thank you for your consideration!!

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing)? "`TestNavHostController` provides a [`setCurrentDestination`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/testing/TestNavHostController#setCurrentDestination(kotlin.Int,android.os.Bundle)) method that allows you to set the current destination so that the NavController is in the correct state before your test begins."

Comment: Yes I have. I read that prior to writing the test. I suppose my issue is not understanding how the safe args component creates the bundle then?

Comment: I'm not sure how to format it. Every time I try to write my own bundle modeled after the safe args component, it tells me I am passing null arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two entirely separate problems here:

**Your Fragment needs to have arguments passed to it.**

Arguments are passed to your fragment via the `fragmentArgs` parameter of `launchFragmentInContainer` as explained in the [Fragment testing guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/test#create).

Each Args class, such as your `LandingFragmentArgs` has a constructor that lets you construct that `Args` class directly. You can then use the `toBundle()` method to make the `Bundle` that you pass to `launchFragmentInContainer`:

```
val args = GameFragmentArgs(/* pass in your required args here */)
val bundle = args.toBundle()
init(launchFragmentInContainer<GameFragment>(fragmentArgs = bundle, themeResId = THEME))
```

**Your NavController needs to have its state set to the GameFragment destination**

Your `TestNavHostController` doesn't know that your test needs to start on the destination associated with `GameFragment` - by default, it will just be on the `startDestination` of your graph (where whatever action you are trying to trigger doesn't exist).

As per the [Test Navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing):

> `TestNavHostController` provides a [`setCurrentDestination`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/testing/TestNavHostController#setCurrentDestination(kotlin.Int,android.os.Bundle)) method that allows you to set the current destination so that the NavController is in the correct state before your test begins.

So you need to make sure you call `setCurrentDestination` after your `init` call:

```
val args = GameFragmentArgs(/* pass in your required args here */)
val bundle = args.toBundle()
val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<GameFragment>(fragmentArgs = bundle, themeResId = THEME)
init(scenario)

// Ensure that the NavController is set to the expected destination
// using the ID from your navigation graph associated with GameFragment
scenario.onFragment {
  // Just like setGraph(), this needs to be called on the main thread
  navController.setCurrentDestination(R.id.game_fragment, bundle)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think to structure the bundle as GameFragmentArgs(..args..)! That certainly clears up my confusion in that aspect. I was trying to pass a normal bundle with identical names.

Comment: However, when I call setCurrentDestination() I still receive the same exception that I did beforehand when calling it. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method setCurrentState must be called on the main thread`

Comment: I had found it in the documentation but couldn't figure out why I kept getting that error, so I'd decided to pursue other solutions in the meantime.

Comment: Ah, yep. `setCurrentDestination`, just like `setGraph`, needs to be on the main thread. You could either make that part of your `init` method (which is generally the correct way of doing it) or use `scenario.onFragment` or any other method in your individual test to get that call onto the main thread.

Comment: Ah, I just found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686001/android-navigation-instrumentation-test-throws-method-addobserver-must-be-called

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much for your time and assistance!